# Layout Issue In HTML5

Tags: css, html

i want to align div from top please help me out how to fix this issue
**my code is:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
        body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .topmenu {
            background-color:#808080;
            height:200px;
            width:600px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="topmenu">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

[Check This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QM2p.png)

Comment: do you want to align div as a header in layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
 body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .topmenu {
            background-color:#808080;
            height:200px;
            width:600px;
        }
        
        h2{
          margin:0;
          }
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="topmenu">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
</nav>
```

With

```
   h2{
      margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.topmenu{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also without adding other class

```
body 
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.topmenu 
{
    background-color:#808080;
    height:200px;
    width:600px;
    margin-top: -19px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.topmenu {
    background-color:#808080;
    height:200px;
    width:600px;
}
       
h2 {
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="topmenu">
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.topmenu 
  {
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
  }
```

Comment: Please read “[How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)”

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are absolutely right. Just wanted to add that it is a good practice to use [reset-css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize-css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) for handling default styling of your webpage. Using them can save you from many styling related hurdles.
As far as the answer is concerned
`h2 {margin:0; padding:0}` should work perfectly!